# Migrate Magnolia CMS encrypted passwords to Joomla CMS?

Tags: php, joomla, md5, magnolia

I have a legacy user database from a Magnolia CMS that needs to be ported to the latest version of Joomla. I have the data in place in the new Joomla database but it (obviously) contains encrypted passwords. What is the best way to ensure that the Magnolia encrypted passwords will work with Joomla? I believe that Magnolia uses MD5??? I'm trying to avoid custom PHP coding but that might be the only way.

Comment: If Magnolia does use MD5 then it should integrate fine with Joomla, as I am pretty sure Joomla uses MD5 as well.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Indeed, they are both MD5 and it ported right over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only way to make sure they work is to port them between two systems that both use the same encryption method. Assuming that both CMS's use the standard MD5, then no problem. otherwise, there's no method for reversing the hashes.

Comment: When I was recently doing this for a site upgrade where the old hash was different and less secure, I implemented the old hash on the new site _as well_ as the new hash. When a migrated user logs in for the first time, I validate the password using the old hash system, then upgrade it to the new one (which I can do at login because the unencrypted password is available during the login request.) This can be a good way of maintaining compatibility while increasing security for any regular users.